# Making a time series of word usage over years

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-dash

I am trying to make a time series plot with plotly on word usage over years. I am basing my code on the first example from: https://plotly.com/python/time-series/?fbclid=IwAR3SZhp7U9pBfdnIyDOnfPdnNkFQXatiysHvhkbAMHbDnkfeFQq0rbN8kj4

In my dataset as shown here:

[image],

i have years as columns and words as rows as generated with pd.DataFrame. I want years to ascend on the x-axis and count to ascend on the y-axis. I want each word to have its own line in the plot. So far my code is :

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.io as pio
pio.renderers.default='browser'
data = pd.read_csv("tabledata.csv")
justcolumns=pd.read_csv("tabledata.csv",index_col=[0])
columnnames=[]
for column in justcolumns.columns:
    columnnames.append(column)

import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.stocks()
fig = px.line(data, x=data.index, y=columnnames)
fig.show()
```

where:

```py
justcolumns=pd.read_csv("tabledata.csv",index_col=[0])
columnnames=[]
for column in justcolumns.columns:
    columnnames.append(column)
```

was a fix to be able to run the code with an apparent "wide dataset". However i am not sure what the inputs for x and y should be in

```py
fig = px.line(data, x=data.index, y=columnnames)
```

or if i need to add any other information to get several lines. Right now i do get values on the y-axis but the x-axis is the words and the colors are the years which is almost reverse of what i want. Output attached below. Any ideas?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the x-axis to be the year, the y-axis to be the frequency number, and the coloring to be the word, you can set x='year',y='freq',color='word' to get the desired graph. See this in the [official reference](https://plotly.com/python/line-charts/#line-charts-with-markers).

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('tabledata.csv',sep=',', index_col=0)
df = df.stack().reset_index().rename(columns={'level_0':'word','level_1':'year',0:'freq'})

import plotly.express as px

fig = px.line(df, x='year', y='freq', color='word', symbol='word')

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer looks very promising, however when I try to implement it i get the error: 
```
KeyError: "None of ['word'] are in the columns"
```
my code looks like this: 
```
data = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("tabledata.csv"),sep=",")
data.set_index("word",inplace=True)
data = data.stack().reset_index().rename(columns={"level_1":"year",0:"freq"})
```

I see you added the "word" to the first row, which is not in my data. I tried running the code without doing it and manually adding it in before, with the same result.

Any ideas?

Comment: I didn't comment that I added the column names. I apologize for that. Once again, I modified the code to read in the format as csv data and converted it to vertical format for the read data. The column names were modified at that time. The output result does not change. Try it with your CSV data.

Comment: Thanks chief, now it works like a charm! Am i understanding it correctly if the .stack is to make it into long format (because we essentially make all year columns into different rows of the same word) and can you tell me why .reset_index is used? I cannot run the code without it, but in my head, that will just take index_col=0 which is "words" and put it as a column again?

Comment: The stack will use the index and columns to transform the vertical format. The result is a word column and a year column that are unindexed. [See this for more details](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html).